# Javascript Run Action on click of a Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Javascript knowledge is extremely low, so sorry for this stupid question, but I have searched everywhere.

I'm using a single page scrolling script, but trying to add a navigation bar. The documentation references this for changing to a page:

```
$(".main").moveTo(3);
```

How do I make a link to run this? I just want a Hyperlink that runs this when clicked, but cannot work out how to do it.

Comment: Here's a [site dedicated to learning](http://www.w3schools.com/default.asp) JavaScript and HTML, CSS, etc.

Comment: And here's a site dedicated to explaining why w3schools is not the best resource to link people to. http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector for the hyperlink as

```
$('a').click(function () {
   // paste your function here..
})
```

You can use a specific selector such as its class as

```
$('a.move').click(function () {
   // function
}
```

Where its HTML will be as

```
<a href="#" class="move">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: href=# is from HTML 3.2, and under HTML4 and HTML5 rules navigates someone to the top of the page. If it's not a link to a resource, don't use `<a>`. In this case, `<button>` with CSS to not necessarily look like a button is the correct HTML5 markup.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't. If the hyperlink does not link to a resource, it's not a hyperlink and you should not use the `<a>` tag. What you're describing is a "click to do something" element, which is the `<button>` element. Simply use this:

```
<button onclick="$('.main').moveTo(3)">click this</button>
```

And then use some CSS to make the button look like whatever you need it to look like (button default styling is just CSS, so turn off the border and background color, and now it looks like plain text)